# Will this subselect be executed before or after the where-clause?

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

Table A has 500'000 records:

```
id, text, created, b_id
```

Table B has 20'000 records:

```
id, text

A.b_id is FK to b.id
```

So when I do the following:

```
SELECT text, created, (SELECT b.text FROM b WHERE b.id = A.b_id) FROM a WHERE created < now()
```

or also

```
SELECT text, created, (SELECT b.text FROM b WHERE b.id = A.b_id) FROM a LIMIT 0,10
```

Will the subselect be executed **after** the WHERE-clause, so actually be only performed on records `where created < now()` resp. only on the first ten records or will it be executed on every record **before** the exclusion happens?

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing a `from` clause in the queries.

Comment: true :) was just an example as my queries would exceed SO storage capabilites ;) will add it though

Comment: Also note that these queries will fail if the subqueries ever return more than one result.

Answer (score 2):

You should learn about SQL joins—for example:

```
SELECT a.text, a.created, b.text
FROM   a JOIN b ON b.id = a.b_id
WHERE  a.created < NOW()
LIMIT  0, 10
```

However, to answer your questions about correlated subqueries:

> Will the subselect be executed after the WHERE-clause, so actually be only performed on records where created < now() resp. only on the first ten records or will it be executed on every record before the exclusion happens?

The subquery will only be evaluated for those records that are returned by the parent query, after its filter/limits have been applied.

Comment: I know very well about SQL joins, my question was about performance and not about other ways to write my code. So if you could provide an answer with your code on the performance / when the join will be executed, that would be helpful, otherwise...

Comment: thanks, so I removed my downvote. Does the same apply for JOINs?

Comment: @RaphaelJeger: With a join, the tables will be accessed only once irrespective of the number of records returned.

Comment: @eggyal
In limit subquery seems more efficient, I am struggling with join

Answer (score 0):

The subquery won't be executed by itself. The entire query will be transformed by the query planner into something that more resembles a query with an outer join.

So, the subquery won't be executed for every record from the other table, or for every record of a intermediate result. It will be executed once, in combination with the main query.

How exactly the query plan ends up depends on what indexes you have on the tables, and what the statistics for the tables tells the query planner.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be the case.  See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ed9d/1).  Indeed, if correlated subqueries were transformed by the query planner into joins then there wouldn't be such a huge disparity in performance, or a need for the manual chapter on [Rewriting Subqueries as Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/rewriting-subqueries.html)?

Comment: @eggyal: By changing the query to measure it, you change the result. You force the query planner to repeat the subquery.

Comment: It produces the same execution plan... see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ed9d/2).

Comment: seems my question wasn't as dumb as I feared it could be ;) In my real-world example, I have 5 subqueries to the same table as my main table is de-normalized - would it benefit performance-wise to re-write it to JOINs instead?

Comment: @RaphaelJeger: I contend that correlated subqueries will always perform worse than joins... Guffa may argue that they sometimes have similar performance, but I've never heard anyone suggest that they can perform better,.

Comment: @eggyal: Yes, subqueries can of course performe worse than joins, but that's not really what this question is about.

Comment: I was merely addressing the OP's question in his comment "*would it benefit performance-wise to re-write it to JOINs instead?*"  As for "*what this question is about*", I stand by my previous comment: it does not appear that "*changing the query to measure it..force[d] the query planner to repeat the subquery*", as the execution plan remains unchanged.  I believe that the correlated subquery is evaluated once for each result returned by the outer query, as my sqlfiddle appears to show.  Would be delighted to discover that I'm wrong, however.